# How to use Protractor / WebDriverJS to check if an element is displayed without waiting?

Tags: protractor, webdriverjs

How to use protractor to check if an element is visible without waiting?
I'm from Java + WebDriver background and new to Protractor. In Java I used the following solution. I'm looking for a similar functionality.

More Information: Currently if I use isDisplayed(), WebDriver will wait until the element is visible (if it is not already displayed). I want to get the visibility status without waiting.

```
protected void turnOffImplicitWaits() {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}



protected void turnOnImplicitWaits() {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(StartupConstants.TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}



protected boolean isElementHiddenNow(By by) {

    turnOffImplicitWaits();

    boolean result = ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by).apply(driver);

    turnOnImplicitWaits();

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Why do you want that - what use case do you want to cover? Is it something like: you have an element that is initially invisible, but then becomes visible and you want to catch it being invisible first..?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any default waits while checking for visibility of element, do one thing, that is just perform any operation like **click()** on target element and add then() function with two functions as parameters - one for success and other for failure. You follow the code below:

```
 var targetElement=element(locator);
 targetElement.click()
                   .then(function(toBeCalledWhenSuccess) { // fulfillment },    
                         function(reasonForRejection) { // rejection }
                        );
```

**Add below code in Conf.js**

```
   jasmineNodeOpts: {
       // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
       defaultTimeoutInterval: 0,
    }
```

Comment: but if the element is not visible webdriver will wait for sometime until it is visible right? I want to get the visibility status without waiting. Can you please confirm?

Comment: I dnt think so. And why do want that specific condition yaar

Comment: Or try to perform any action on element and use code - targetElement.click().then(function(value) {
   // fulfillment
  }, function(reasonForRejection) {
  // rejection
});

Comment: in above case, if element is not visible or clickable, it will immediately throw an error that will be sent as parameter to second function(reasonForRejection){} method in then()

Comment: And you can do what do you want

Comment: This is something I was looking for. Thanks for the information I will check it.

Comment: When you define var targetElement=element(locator); and if the element is not displayed, WebDriver waits until it appear with its default timeout.So still its not going to solve it.

Comment: @Umesh_IoT, just change _defaultTimeoutInterval:_, to zero (0) in conf.js file. I've updated my post